# How to tell if a bookmark already exists in Safari (v6.0.5)

Tags: safari, bookmarks

I find I often wrestle with the implementation of bookmarks in Safari.  Since I care to have my bookmarks simply and cleanly synchronized by iCloud, I continue to use the (inadequate) bookmark features of Safari.  My specific question is: Is there a way to tell if a site is already bookmarked?  I have 1000s of bookmarks, organized by folders.  It seems pretty straightforward for Safari to know when I hit CMD-D to initiate a bookmark that it already exists in my collection.  Am I missing this feature that is already implemented?

Comment: This is a basic and important feature. It is surprising why Safari does not have it.

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox flag if a bookmark already exists. Hope Safari goes this route soon! :)

Comment: I don’t know of a way to do what you’re asking, but it would be a damn-nifty feature.

Comment: It's 2021 now, and the problem is still not solved!

Comment: 10 years later, we are still missing this basic feature.

Answer (score 3):

Safari has a bookmark search function in the top right corner of the bookmark menu window,

Just paste the new bookmark (or type first 3 letters) in to it and it will tell you if it already exist.

It is also useful in finding bookmarks in a very large library.

[image]

Comment: That is one way.  But, if you are ready to bookmark a page, you have to at least open a new tab, click copy/paste the prospective bookmark, and see what comes up.  It seems like an obvious feature is to have the "Add bookmark..." shortcut (CMD-D) have feedback on existing bookmarks.  I suppose what you are really saying is that that feature does not presently exist (either as shipped or with an add-on)?

Comment: And dammit, that Safari bookmark search function can't distinguish between Bookmarks and History, which makes it way less useful.

Comment: @Zo219 Indeed.  I wonder if it possible for a Safari extension to implement this sort of feature (ie., add a "flag" to the Add Bookmark... shortcut dialog to indicate if a bookmark already exists).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheeky, long-winded approach with all keyboard shortcuts to copy the URL and search in bookmarks editor:

**TLDR: ⌘L then ⌘C then ⌥⌘B then ⌘F then ⌘V**

When done, close bookmark editor: ⌥⌘B

I'm wondering if there's a good bookmark manager workflow in **Alfred** that includes deleting (**the stock Alfred bookmark feature will search and open bookmarks**).